# Does Abaddon's compendium immortal item, Mace of the Chosen, have any unique effects?

Tags: dota-2

So... does the Abaddon immortal item from the 2013 compendium, Mace of the Chosen, modify anything? I am pretty sure it doesn't change the normal attacks. Curse of Avernus, Shadow Coil, and Borrowed Time seem to be unchanged as well. So am I missing something, or is it just a weapon model change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally, it didn't change any effects, but in the July 30th, 2013 patch, they added a new effect for Apothic Shield, which basically removes the transparency on the black behind the swirls:

Normal:
[image: Normal Apothic Shield]

With Mace of the Chosen:
[image: Mace Apothic Shield]

Here's a video of the new effect:

Comment: I love how they have done it. It still fits the hero color pattern, but it is noticeably different.